# Http published .net core project give a no-referrer-when-downgrade

Tags: .net, http, asp.net-core, iis, vs-web-site-project

I tried to published locally web page. I access to webpage on laptops or desktop pc's web browser but when I tried on Android google chrome, return "ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE" error. my website adress is : **http://192.168.x.yz:abcd**
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

I also set in chrome://flags , "Insecure origins treated as secure" Enabled and add http://192.168.x.yz:abcd adding.

webconfig file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\MyProjectImportantWeb.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Hi, did your web page published as a public website? And did you test in another browser with that android device? And test in other android device? Because we can't make sure if the issue comes from your application or device or chrome.

Comment: hi, thank you for reply, yes I tried another browser(Firefox) and run stable. But when I tried Chrome , I have some issues, ie: loading modal couldnt close. And loading time spend more.. But In firefox, my website running more stable. But stilll I cant figure out why chrome has a some issue

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply and as you mentioned that the issue points to chrome browser, I really have no other ideas on it, I think you may delete and create a new case to describe this compatibility phenomenon with chrome tag to acquire professional assistance.